# How can I add another form in signup form django

Tags: python, django

this is my code:

views.py

```
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
form_class = SignUpForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='Required.')
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='Required.')
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, required=True , help_text='Required.')

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('location','phone')
```

i don't know how to extend signupform with profileform, i want user to submit together since signup

Comment: What do you mean by `Another Form` ?

Comment: I mean I have original signup form of django(username,firstname,lastname,email,password1&2) but I want some more infomation so I just created another form about bio form(phone,address,gender,age) and this is the problem I want to merge my original signup form and my new bio form in signup page and submit it at the same time

Comment: I hope you can help me Im stuck with this for 3 days

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like :-

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    username = forms.CharField(help_text=False)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = forms.IntegerField()
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    age = forms.IntegerField()

    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'address',
            'phone',
            'gender',
            'age',
            'email',            
            'username',

        )
```

signup.html

```
{% extends "mains/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

  <form method="post" action="{% url 'users:signup_view' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Register</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

(The code is Successfully Tested and Worked)

*You can also use [Django Crispy Forms](https://pypi.org/project/django-crispy-forms/) to look forms more beautiful and decent.*